# HttpClient fails to respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnet-httpclient

I have a Asp.Net Core (2.1) website using [Asp.Net Boilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/).

I'm trying to make a API call using `HttpClient`, which works locally, but throws an error when deployed to IIS.

I created a `TypedClient`

```
public class FormsHttpClient : IFormsHttpClient
{
    private const string url = "my_url:3001/";
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public FormsHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

        _client = httpClient;
    }
    ....
}
```

In my `startup.cs` file, I added:

`services.AddHttpClient<IFormsHttpClient, FormsHttpClient>();`

The error i get when i deploy:

> ERROR 2018-12-12 18:30:29,509 [11   ] Mvc.ExceptionHandling.AbpExceptionFilter - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>      at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The network call normally takes 1800ms to finish, it seems to timeout around 21000ms.

I came across the code `AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.useSocketsHttpHandler", false);`, thought i wasn't sure where to put it, i tossed it in the constructor of my `startup.cs` class but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is there something else im missing?

E: The code that calls the api is in JS:

```
   app.forms.token = {
    generate: function () {
        Formio.logout();
        abp.services.app.forms.generateFormToken().done(function (e) {
            Formio.setToken(e);
        });
    },
    clear: function () {
        Formio.logout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you making the request?! This is just registering service...

Comment: If it works locally, then your code is fine. Are you sure you can actually reach that web service (my_url:3001) from the server you deployed this to?

Comment: @kos making the request in JS, the call returns `500` @gabriel, i can make the same api call in postman from the same device, so i can definitely access it. It seems the be the failing on any `HttpClient's` `PostAsync` or `GetAsync`, depending on which call i make

Comment: That might be issue with that my_url:3001 service. In production you are requesting something that make it die. I would try to use some tool to capture the request like fiddler to investigate furder...

Comment: @Kos thanks. I figured out a work around which is probably a good solution of its own. I had to change the IP to an internal IP (10.200.x.xx) for my server code and keep using the public IP in client side code. I was basically trying to access the same server on a different port. learning is fun =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am communicating with the same machine but different port, I changed the public IP in my server code to an internal IP and my problem was resolved.

I've made it a rule of thumb to use internal IP in server code and public IP in client code. If this is bad practice, let me know.

Comment: It's not a bad idea, it can help sometimes if running something very busy to keep port usage down. It's hard to tell if that is what caused your program to work better, but I'm glad it worked.